# Prevent multiple roles for a user in suitecrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I got a requirement in Suitecrm to prevent giving multiple roles for a same user who have been assigned a role already. How to prevent giving multiple roles for a user in suitecrm.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the use case for wanting to prevent multiple roles? I ask as it could be a work around for something else that is solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override pop view for users using this link: [here](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/22675)

Add a check there to display only those users for a role which doesn't belong to any role. Hopefully you can write logic for finding users without role(s)

Comment: Thank you. let me check.

Comment: Hi Abdul, unfortunately i couldnt find the viewpopup.php. Actally once we login as Admin, roles management section will be there, once we open a list of roles will be there. At the end of roles detail page, there will be an option to add users to it. So once we click on the 'select user' button, it will open a pop, there no user should come if he is already assigned to a role. Can you please tell me which files i have to edit and where should i write the db query. Thanks.

Comment: I am using Version 7.5.3

Sugar Version 6.5.23